# how use button in internet explorer?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, hyperlink

on my source i use

```
<a href='pag.php'><input type='button' value='Next'/></a>
```

in firefox and crome when i click on the button i'm redirected to pag.php
but in ie it don't work. how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is:

```
<input type='button' value='Next' onclick="location.href='pag.php'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form buttons are meant to be used for submitting a form to the page specified in the `action` attribute, not to be wrapped in `<a>` tags, which is bad syntax. If this is for a multi-part form, simply add the `action` attribute to the `<form>` tag like

```
<form method="POST" action="pag.php">
    <!-- your form elements -->
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

And that will submit the form to `pag.php`. Otherwise, just use a link, or, if you insist on having it look like a button, use an image link like:

```
<a href="pag.php"><img src="image_that_looks_like_a_button.png"></a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "button" type of input doesn't submit the form.

Comment: "submit" does :) Had "button" in my mind and it slipped through. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: An untyped button element does submit the form in webkit and mozilla (the default button type is "submit") -- in IE, the default type is "button".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what you are doing right now, go for:

```
<form action="pag.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="Submit" value="Next">

</form>
```

But if you want image instead in place of button, go for:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="image location" ALT="Next">
```

Hope it solves your problem! :)